# How to set roles or remove authorization requirement for deployed application in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, user-roles

I'm new in Tomcat and whole Java.
I installed Tomcat and set up admin role.

Then download and build sample application using Maven.

Then I deployed .war file into Tomcat and it appeared in Tomcat Applications Manager (localhost:8080/manager/html).

But when I tries to open deployed application, Tomcat asks me for username and password. I can't open application under admin - gives 403.

My `tomcat-users.xml`:

```xml
<tomcat-users>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

What role must I give for user (admin or other) for application will be able to opened?
Or, better, remove login requirement for deployed application.

Comment: It wants the username/password of the application. Nothing to do with the manager app.

Comment: @EJP `tomcat-users.xml` can be used by any application, not just Tomcat's manager application. But it would be odd indeed for a 3rd-party application to rely on `tomcat-users.xml` for a handful of reasons. This problem likely has nothing to do with `tomcat-users.xml`.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz That's what I said. It's proven by the fact that he was already logged into the manager application. If the second app was using `tomcat-users.xml` it would have succeeded.